# Successfully getting DL members-but how to check for and to list nested groups and members?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-exchange

My script pulls members from each DL listed in my txt file, but there's a few that have security groups as members and I would like to list out the members in those groups as well.

```
set-adserversetting -viewentireforest $true

$groups = Get-Content -path 'C:\Users\test.txt'

$result = 
foreach ($group in $groups) {
$members = Get-DistributionGroupMember -$group -ResultSize Unlimited
foreach ($user in $members) {
[PSCustomObject]@{
GroupName = $group
samAccountName = $user.samAccountName
distinguishedName = $user.distinguishedName
name = $user.name
}
}
}
$result | export-csv 'C:\Users\testing.csv' -notypeinformation
```

Comment: `$members.Count` is always 1 on each iteration? The code seems ok at first glance.

Comment: The dash before $group should not be there `Get-DistributionGroupMember -$group`

Comment: @Daniel excellent catch, didn't see that one!

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function for this.

Try:

```
function Get-NestedDistributionGroupMembers {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$Group
    )
    # Identity can be Name, Alias, DistinguishedName, CanonicalName, EmailAddress or GUID
    $searchGroup = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group -ResultSize Unlimited
    foreach ($member in $searchGroup) {
        if ($member.RecipientTypeDetails.Value -match "Group") {
            Get-NestedDistributionGroupMembers $member.DistinguishedName
        }           
        else {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                GroupName         = $searchGroup.DisplayName
                SamAccountName    = $member.samAccountName
                DistinguishedName = $member.distinguishedName
                Name              = $member.name
            }
        }
    }
}

$groups = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\test.txt'
$result = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-NestedDistributionGroupMembers $group
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\testing.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```